# Best AWS server for eCommerce

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to deploy my Laravel app to AWS server and I got two options:

1. ECS services which allow me to use docker to manage the number of services I need (Ram, CPU ..etc)
2. AWS eCommerce Platform to set monthly plan services (static number of Ram, CPU, and storage according to the plan)

So which one should I use for my e-commerce platform? comparing should contain:

- performance: which one is better to deal with API requests (I heard docker slows down the processing)
- price: is it safer to choose a monthly plan instead of cost by view or resources?
- security: AWS offers more security options on the AWS e-commerce platform

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with managing your own instance is that you have to work out security aspects deeply especially if you are handling payments or credit card information. Considering e-commerce site this may be at the core of requirement. Personally i will go for a managed service rather than ECS, as you be spending a lot of time configuring and securing ECS.IN ECS case you have to buy a SSL certificate on top, plus penetration testing to make sure site is secure etc.
The managed platform is hopefully already PCI-DSS compliant and easy to configure.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation, one more thing can I install lets-encrypt SSL on both servers?

Comment: on SAS service you be subscribing to the SSL service where as on the ECS you have to buy it, install it and secure the site. In a way yes you can on both the services where as one is easy and the other one is little bit tricky.